# Selecting an element by id from store in angular

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngredux

I have the following data in the store:

```
{
 properties : 
  [
   {
    _id: 123.
    name: "Nice property"
   },
   {
    _id: 456.
    name: "Another nice property"
   }
 ]
}
```

In my `ngOnInit` method I would like to select a property from the store mathcing an id that was passed as a queryParam like this:

```
javascript
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.property = this.ngRedux.select( state => state.properties).pipe(find( property => property._id === this.id))
```

Obviously, this does not work, but it catches the spirit of what I am trying to do.

Googling selecting by id using ngRedux brings very little, so I have a suspicion that I am doing this the wrong way.

I have tried resolving this using `.subscribe`, however, then all the logic must be in the subscribe callback, which seems wrong and did not work when I tried to make a reactive form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.property = this.store.select((state) => state.properties)
    .pipe(map(properties => properties.find(x => x_.id == this.id)));
```

This should work for your given scenario. You simply select properties from the store and then return the first property which matches your id.

Comment: My store is ngRedux and `.pipe` does not exist on it. I need to write `.select` after store and then I can use `.pipe`, but still not having any luck.

Comment: Have you tried doing .select then piping the map operator to get the property?

Comment: Yes @Viqas that turned out the be the right to thing to do. Thank you and sorry for taking so long to get back :) Could you change your answer to reflect that so I can mark it as the right answer?